# Operation with big integers

Tags: .net, visual-c++, c++-cli, biginteger

I wrote simple C++/CLI code to calculate a result of big integer numbers operation, but it failed with the warning warning `C4307: '*' : integral constant overflow`, here is my code:

```
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    String^ number = gcnew String((wchar_t *)(28433 * (2 ^ 7830457) + 1));

    Console::WriteLine(number);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of fundamental misunderstandings in your code:

1. You're not using big integers anywhere
2. `^` is xor, and not exponentiation.
3. You're casting that integer to a pointer, which is a meaningless operation

You should use the [`BigInteger` struct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) from `System.Numerics`. Don't forget to add the assembly reference to `System.Numerics.dll` first.

Answer (score 1):

2 ^ 7830457 require 7830457 bits to store. Around 1MB just for one number !
You should start by learning variables types and the values they can handle. Do you really need an exact integer value for this number ? Do you really need to display it ? This umber is several millions of char long.

You can't use regular  */-+^ operators with such numbers, you need an arbitrary large number math library. And I fear it won't even handle such large number.
[How to handle arbitrarily large integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310276/how-to-handle-arbitrarily-large-integers)