# How to scanf long long long int in C

Tags: c, scanf

I have tried scanning `long long` integers succesfully; but, I don't know how to scan larger integers than `long long`. How would one scan Integers *bigger* than `long long` in c? For instance, `long long long`.

Comment: There is no `long long long`. To use really big numbers see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310276/how-to-handle-arbitrarily-large-integers.

Answer (score 7):

There is no standard library function which is guaranteed to work with integers wider than `long long int`. And there is no portable datatype which is wider than `long long int`. (Also, `long long int` is not guaranteed to be longer than 64 bits, which might also be the width of `long`.)

In other words, if you want to work with very large integers, you'll need a library. These are typically called "bignum libraries", and you'll have little trouble searching for one.

**Edit** (including the theoretical possibility that the implementation has another integer type, as noted by @chux):

In theory, a C implementation may have integers wider than `long long`, in which case the widest such integer types (signed and unsigned) would be called `intmax_t` and `uintmax_t`. Otherwise, and more commonly, `intmax_t` and `uintmax_t` are typedefs for `long long` and `unsigned long long`. You can use `intmax_t` variables in `scanf` and `printf` functions by applying the length modifier `j`. For example:

```
/* Needed for intmax_t */
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  intmax_t probably_long_long;
  if (1 == scanf("%jd", &probably_long_long))
    printf("The number read was %jd\n", probably_long_long);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: "no standard library function which works with integers wider than `long long int`"  Hmmm  `intmax_t, strtoimax(), strtoumax(), imaxdiv(), imaxabs()` etc. have the potential to be wider.

Comment: @chux: true, if intmax_t is not the same as long long. But I believe that OP really is looking for a bignum library. All the same, edited.

Comment: also `intNNN_t` may be wider than `long long int`

Comment: it's a bit weird that gcc has `__int128` but makes `intmax_t` smaller than that

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Nothing in my answer denies the existence of potential types wider than long long and narrower than intmax_t. It just doesn't name them. I suppose that `__int128` is not considered an extended integer type because if it were, `intmax_t` would have to be (at least) 128 bits wide, and then the printf/scanf formats mentioned would have to work. But, afaik, they don't. In fact, I don't believe you can even use numeric literals wider than 64 bits...